# Best approach to providing book recommendations to augment an answer

Tags: discussion, answers

I often read a question, to which a part of my answer could easily be simply put...

**Read a book.**

To be a little more helpful, I have begun suggesting a couple of titles that helped me enormously when I began the process of learning Objective C and Xcode and in particular Core Data, I include the author's name and a chapter reference. I have done this a few times now and even have a snippet saved in Notes for quick and easy access.

I have read these web pages - [How to reference material written by others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) and [Answering](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Could you please provide advice as to whether the inclusion of (seemingly repetitive) book recommendations is an acceptable form of augmenting an answer?

Comment: a book rec is definitely not a valid answer per se, but it seems acceptable as a part of the answer.

Comment: It is okay (and preferred) to reference something if you take an excerpt from it. However, if you refer to very specific books (like, only 1 or 2), try not to look as advertisement, by putting a disclaimer.